# Hibernate mapping: many to many with fk not having the same name?

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to map a many-to-many relationship but my middle table is giving me trouble because the names don't match.

table1:

```
**userId**
firstname
lastname
```

table2:

```
**user_id** <= fk to table1.userId 
x_id
create_date
```

table3:

```
x_id
private1
private2
```

Could anyone give me a pointer how I should map this?

```
<list name="xlist" table="table2" lazy="false">
                <key column="user_id"/>
                <index column="creatie_dt"/>
                <many-to-many column="x_id" class="X"/>
        </list>
```

Doesn't seem like the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to a set solved my problems.